# Cannot step into SQL Server stored procedure in Visual Stuidio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have inherited a SQL Server stored procedure that I need to step through, and since debugging is no longer in SSMS I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2019. Here are the steps I'm using. I open Visual Studio and choose continue without code. Then I create a new data connection, right click the db and choose "New Query".

I paste in this

```
EXEC _healthandwelfare_rev4
        @bachnumb = N'TMW20210306',
        @prenddate = N'03-06-2021',
        @includeunpaidfte = 1,
        @fullrecalc = 1
```

I then set a break point on it, and use the SQL menu to Execute with Debugger. The issue is it just runs the whole thing and never stops to give me the step options. Honestly really stumped here on what I'm missing.

Comment: You need the definition of the procedure, and then you need to debug that. If the definition of the procedure isn't in your project, then the project will have no idea how to debug it.

Comment: It is possible to install SSIS 17.9.1 and debug the SP in question there. That version of SSIS can co-exist with SSIS 18.*

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot debug a SP in Visual Studio by the way you are doing.

1. In the First place you should have a database project and the SP definition in the project to debug step through it.
2. You can debug the SP by pasting its definition,(the whole SP) and comment out the create procedure section and declare the input parameters on the top and assign values and place Break points at the top and debug it.
3. If you are using Visuals Studio 2019 then the below link may be helpful to you
   [Debug Stored Proc in VS2019](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-debug-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-using-visual-studio-2019/)

Comment: It is Version 2019. I followed that entirely, and I do now get the right click debug procedure option. It asks for the parameters, then just runs it all.

Comment: I did a new query, copied the proc, removed the alter proc part and did the declarations. Put a break in, did SQL execute with debugger. Again it just runs fully. Does it matter that this proc doesn't really return any data?

Comment: It depends on your SPs logic, not all SPs will need to return data. But check your SP Whether it has a select statement at the end of the procedure. If so it should return data. And  Execute with debugger should hit the break point.

Comment: To be clear I know it doesn't return any it just manipulates tables and does some calculations. I just wasn't sure if maybe that was why the debugger won't step. I'm really quite stumped here as to why it won't actually debug and give me the step options.

Comment: Execute with debugger should place a breakpoint to the start of you SP and hit the breakpoint, even I'm wondering what's wrong.. Just to confirm.. are you using Execute With Debugger (Alt + F5) Option?

Comment: I'm using it directly from the drop down file menu, my understanding is that it should also do that if you use the right click debug procedure, but neither break the code.